# Set binding value as a parameter on a behavior in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding, label, behavior

How do I set a binding value as a parameter on a behavior in Xamarin Forms?

When I do this I get:
Error. No property, bindable property, or event found for 'InputValue', or mismatching type between value and property.

XAML:

```
<Label Grid.Column="0" x:Name="player" FontSize="Small" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                       Text="{Binding FormattedName}" >
                                    <Label.Behaviors>
                                        <local:ColorTextLabelBehavior MaxInputValue="100" MinInputValue="0" InputValue="{Binding Happiness}" />
                                    </Label.Behaviors>
                                </Label>
```

C#:

```
public class ColorTextLabelBehavior : Behavior<Label>
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty MaxValue = BindableProperty.Create("MaxValue", typeof(int), typeof(ColorTextLabelBehavior), defaultValue: 100);
    public static readonly BindableProperty MinValue = BindableProperty.Create("MinValue", typeof(int), typeof(ColorTextLabelBehavior), defaultValue: 0);
    public static readonly BindableProperty ActualValue = BindableProperty.Create("ActualValue", typeof(int), typeof(ColorTextLabelBehavior), defaultValue: 100);

    public int MaxInputValue
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(MaxValue); }
        set { SetValue(MaxValue, value); }
    }
    public int MinInputValue
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(MinValue); }
        set { SetValue(MinValue, value); }
    }
    public int InputValue
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ActualValue); }
        set { SetValue(ActualValue, value); }
    }

    void HandleTextChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            float percent = ((float)InputValue - (float)MinInputValue) / ((float)MaxInputValue - (float)MinInputValue);
            double resultRed = Color.Red.R + percent * (Color.Green.R - Color.Red.R);
            double resultGreen = Color.Red.G + percent * (Color.Green.G - Color.Red.G);
            double resultBlue = Color.Red.B + percent * (Color.Green.B - Color.Red.B);
            ((Label)sender).TextColor = new Color(resultRed, resultGreen, resultBlue);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(BindableObject bindable)
    {
        bindable.PropertyChanged += HandleTextChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(BindableObject bindable)
    {
        bindable.PropertyChanged += HandleTextChanged;
    }
}
```

If I hard code a value for 'InputValue' this works, but I want to be able to send a binding so that it will auto color the text.

Note this is in a listview if that matters.

Please help, I've been stuck on this and can't find any answers.
I'm open to other alternatives to implementing this as well.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the exact naming is important and that the `BindableProperty` has to have the name of the actual property with "Property" appended to the end. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties#creating-a-property):

> The naming convention for bindable properties is that the bindable property identifier must match the property name specified in the Create method, with "Property" appended to it.

So I believe you want something like this:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty MaxInputValueProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(MaxInputValue), typeof(int), typeof(ColorTextLabelBehavior), defaultValue: 100);
public static readonly BindableProperty MinInputValueProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(MinInputValue), typeof(int), typeof(ColorTextLabelBehavior), defaultValue: 0);
public static readonly BindableProperty InputValueProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(InputValue), typeof(int), typeof(ColorTextLabelBehavior), defaultValue: 100);

public int MaxInputValue
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(MaxValue); }
    set { SetValue(MaxValue, value); }
}
public int MinInputValue
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(MinValue); }
    set { SetValue(MinValue, value); }
}
public int InputValue
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(ActualValue); }
    set { SetValue(ActualValue, value); }
}
```

Comment: I refactored my code to look like this and I am no longer getting errors, however InputValue is always the default 100, not the binding I send in -

 public static BindableProperty InputValueProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(InputValue), typeof(int), typeof(ColorTextLabelBehavior), defaultValue: 100);


 public int InputValue
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(InputValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(InputValueProperty, value); }
        }

Comment: So ask a new question as to why the binding is not working. You would need to show the XAML code as well.

Comment: A quick look reveals a possible issue. You may need to call `base` in the `OnAttachedTo` and `OnDetachingFrom` methods, e.g.: `base.onAttachedTo(bindable)`, but also you are inheriting from `Behavior<Label>` but then you say this is an `Entry`. If so, you need to inherit from Behavior<Entry>. If this does not help, post a new question. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/creating#creating-a-xamarinforms-behavior

Comment: Also since this answer solved the initial error, can you please accept it as an answer? thanks.

Comment: Thank you for helping me solve this issue. I created another question here for the other issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54102145/binding-not-working-for-behavior-parameter-c-sharp-xamarin

Comment: So I made a detailed answer to your new question, but when I went to post the answer, you had deleted the question. I will put my answer above since I spent time on it. My suggestion is to use a value converter instead of a behavior, which is a better fir for what you seem to want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem is quite simple

if you check your `BindableProperty` for `ActualValue`:

```
 public int InputValue
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(ActualValue); }
    set { SetValue(ActualValue, value); }
}

public static readonly BindableProperty ActualValue = BindableProperty.Create("ActualValue", typeof(int), typeof(ColorTextLabelBehavior), defaultValue: 100);
```

You are setting the name of the property as `ActualValue` when it should be the name of the associated property and not the Binding field hence your property should be something like this:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty ActualValue = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(InputValue), typeof(int), typeof(ColorTextLabelBehavior), defaultValue: 100);

public int InputValue
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(ActualValue); }
    set { SetValue(ActualValue, value); }
}
```

Correct the same for the other two properties as well.

also note `nameof(InputValue)` is the same as "InputValue" and using `nameof()` is the standard way of doing it

Comment: I tried doing this and I still get the same error, it instantly fails when running. It seems like the behavior will not allow a binding to one of the parameters.